# Flask-RESTful vs Flask-RESTplus

Tags: flask, flask-restful, flask-restplus

Other than the ability to automatically generate an interactive documentation for our API using Swagger UI, are there any real advantages of using [Flask-RESTplus](http://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) over [Flask-RESTful](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/)?

Comment: I concur: considering how similar the two APIs are, it would be really nice to hear from people who have experienced both…

Comment: the author of flask-restplus just added some maintainers to the project from the same issue:
https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/593

Comment: FYI: There's a new community driven fork https://github.com/python-restx/flask-restx

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**update** When reading this accepted answer, consider that there is [Flask-RESTX](https://github.com/python-restx/flask-restx) which is a fork of Flask-RESTPlus that is maintained, as an alternative option.

I am aware of the fact that this answer is probably too late, but it still might be helpful in the future.

According to https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/593, the Flask Restplus is most probably dead and abandoned. The last commit was on October 1, 2018. It looks like the project is not being actively maintained anymore.

Therefore, I advise that you use Flask Restful despite the auto generated Swagger docs in Restplus. Since Restplus is not maintained, it is most likely that the implementation will sooner or later go out of date. Rather than switching to Restful once Restplus goes out of date, I think starting off with Restful itself would be the better idea here.

Just my two cents... :)

Comment: Looks like the project is not going to die after all. According to this [post](https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/593#issuecomment-474389080),  noirbizarre, the creator of the project is looking to onboard new maintainers and keep the project alive.

Comment: Yeup, not abandoned. See also this post: https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/612: "Flask-restplus future organization and roadmap".

Comment: old news, the project is actively maintained as of today. The last commit was 3 days ago https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/commits/master :)

Comment: Update: RESTPlus has been forked to RESTX (adding some more confusion to the mix..)

https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/pull/769

Comment: I haven't compared these myself, but if the only noticeable trick being added by `ReSTplus` is `Swagger documentation` (as noted by others), as well as the on-again / off-again / fork-again instability seen (again, as noted by others), why risk using it? Don't we have enough technology to read, learn and keep track of in this short life? Just stick with `Flask-ReSTful` and make it work for you like commenter @roipoussiere suggested. :)

Comment: There is now also [Flask-RESTX](https://flask-restx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which is a fork of Flask-RESTPlus that is maintained, as a better option.

Comment: Three years later... doesn't seem like it was kept alive afterall?

Answer (score 84):

I've used both, and the only reason we switched to Flask-restplus was the desire to have auto generated Swagger documentation. In my experience, there are no other noticeable differences. Flask-RESTplus started as a fork of Flask-RESTful, so if you were so inclined, you could read the commit history and see if there are any other noticeable differences.

Comment: We also used Flask-restplus for this reason.

Comment: Note that if your only reason to use flask-RESTplus is the generated documentation, you can use Flask-RESTful among with flasgger (https://github.com/rochacbruno/flasgger), that is *a Flask extension to extract OpenAPI=Specification from all Flask views registered in your API.*

Comment: You should probably mention Flask-RESTX

Answer (score 0):

**update** You should also consider using FastAPI which is a framework that is becoming popular (see google trends). And, differently from Flask: has built-in data validation, supports asynchronous tasks and you also get the Swagger UI.

You stablish the endpoints with decorators like in Flask and it is reportedly faster.

Check: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/

Hope it helps.